# swift uipageviewcontroller dynamically change navigationOrientation

Tags: navigation, uipageviewcontroller, swift4

I am using `UIPageViewController` to navigate between views like snapchat.
But, here is the problem: In my third views containing swipe actions (left and right) `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` so I must change the navigation orientation to do `.vertical` but I couldn't do because it's constant. How can achieve this?

**UIPageViewController:** 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller

**Navigation Orientation:** https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontrollernavigationorientation

**AppDelegate:**

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var orientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation = .horizontal
    var rootViewController: PageViewController?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        window = UIWindow()
        rootViewController = PageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: orientation, options: nil)
        window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
}
```

**PageViewController:**

```
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    var indexForViewControllerLoad = 0

    lazy var subViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
        return[
            UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC1") as! VC1,
            UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC2") as! VC2,
            UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC3") as! VC3
        ]
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self
        setViewControllers([subViewControllers[indexForViewControllerLoad]], direction: .forward , animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return subViewControllers.count
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var index = indexOfViewController(viewController: viewController)!
        if (index != -1)
        {
            index = index + 1
            if (index >= subViewControllers.count)
            {
                return nil
            }
            else
            {
                return subViewControllers[index]
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var index = indexOfViewController(viewController: viewController)!
        if (index != -1)
        {
            index = index - 1
            if (index < 0)
            {
                return nil
            }
            else
            {
                return subViewControllers[index]
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func indexOfViewController(viewController : UIViewController) -> Int?
    {
        for i in 0...subViewControllers.count {
            if (viewController == subViewControllers[i])
            {
                return i
            }
        }
        return -1
    }
}
```

**UPDATED:**

I have 3 controllers and views on my app.

I want to navigate first view and second view horizontally, when in third view want to vertically navigate to first view like snapchat. 
If I inspect the snapchat the views is opening on the view like below images:

[Horizontal swiping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JbMd.jpg)

[Vertical swiping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKdLy.jpg)

Comment: So you want to swipe left and right, but on one page, you want to swipe up/down?

Comment: Yes sir, i want to swipe pages up/down/left/right.

Comment: This is *horrible* UX design. You tell your users "You can navigate by swiping left and right" and then you throw them a curveball by making left and right do something completely different. It's like Skype not closing when you click close. It's beyond awful!